# Node - async function inside an imported module

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have a Node 14 server which is initialized like this:

```
import express, { Express } from 'express';
import kafkaConsumer from './modules/kafkaConsumer';

async function bootstrap(): Promise<Express> {

    kafkaConsumer();

    const app = express();

    app.get('/health', (_req, res) => {
        res.send('ok');
    });

    return app;
}

export default bootstrap;
```

`kafkaConsumer` code:

```
import logger from './logger.utils';
import KafkaConnector from '../connectors/kafkaConnector';

// singleton
const connectorInstance: KafkaConnector = new KafkaConnector('kafka endpoints', 'consumer group name');

// creating consumer and producer outside of main function in order to not initialize a new consumer producer per each new call.
(async () => {
  await connectorInstance.createConsumer('consumer group name');
})();

const kafkaConsumer = async (): Promise<void> => {
  
  const kafkaConsumer = connectorInstance.getConsumer();

  await kafkaConsumer.connect();
  await kafkaConsumer.subscribe({ topic: 'topic1', fromBeginning: true });

  await kafkaConsumer.run({
    autoCommit: false, // cancel auto commit in order to control committing
    eachMessage: async ({ topic, partition, message }) => {
      const messageContent = message.value ? message.value.toString() : '';
      logger.info('received message', {
        partition,
        offset: message.offset,
        value: messageContent,
        topic
      });

      // commit message once finished  all processing
      await kafkaConsumer.commitOffsets([ { topic, partition, offset: message.offset } ]);
    }
  });

};

export default kafkaConsumer;
```

You can see that in the `kafkaConsumer` module there's an async function which is called at the begging to initialize the consumer instance.

How can I guarantee that it successfully passed when importing the module?

In addition, when importing the module, does this mean that the `kafkaConsumer` default function, is automatically called? won't it cause the server to be essentially stuck at startup?

Would appreciate some guidance here, thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Twicked the Kafka initalzation, and tested with local Kafka. Everything works as expected.

Comment: I downvoted because the question is _"How can I guarantee that it successfully passed when importing the module?"_ With the given code, it's not guaranteed. It's possible, that `await connectorInstance.createConsumer('consumer group name');` is still running after the module is imported. This answer is misleading.